# CPanel Rearrange account can't find home2

Tags: cpanel, linux, whm, centos

I want to move an account using WHM/CPanel from the /home folder to /home2 folder, but the tool does not find the /home2, it says: "The user is already installed on the only usable partition on this machine. "

This is what I've done so far:

- I mounted a new, formated ext4 disk at /home2 with 600GB free disk
  space
- The new partition at /home2 is accessible and I tested it
  creating a text file as root
- I rebooted the server (several times)
- in Basic Webhost Manager Setup, in "Enter the location where you wish for new users’ home directories to be created" I left the default => "/home"

Is there anything else that has to be done so CPanel finds the /home2 folder?

Comment: Have you tried contacting cpanel support or used a cpanel forum?  This is pretty specialised.

Comment: @Steve I did, it was better than expected, they answered in 8:30 hours. I thought this was going to take more than 48 hours so I asked here.

Comment: It's a miracle!!! :o)

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted CPanel's support. The problem was you need to setup 2 variables in En **WHM -> Server Configuration -> Basic WebHost Manager® Setup**, **HOMEMATCH** and **HOMEDIR**
I was changing just the 1st one.

You can check it in the shell using:

```
 # grep home /etc/wwwacct.conf -i
 HOMEMATCH home
 HOMEDIR /home
```